# Ghoshscript total coverage "incorrect"

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript (version 9.2) Linux version to convert PS to PDF file. Below is the script

```
#!/bin/ksh

/home/ghostscript/ps2pdf \
-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE  \
-dEmbedAllFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages=/None \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
-r1440 \
-dOverrideICC=true \
-dUsePDFX3Profile=1 \
-sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK \
-sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK   \
-sICCProfilesDir=/home/ghostscript/ \
-sDefaultRGBProfile=AdobeRGB1998.icc \
-sOutputICCProfile=ISOnewspaper26v4.icc \
-sImageICCProfile=ISOnewspaper26v4.icc \
-sFONTPATH=/opt/igenfonts \
-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=779.76 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1035.36 \
-sOutputFile=$1.pdf \
 $1.PS
```

ISOnewspaper26v4.icc is a Total Coverage 240 ICC profile from http://www.color.org. PDF is converted successfully. But in Adobe Acrobat 8.0 profressional, total coverage of 240 shows color saturation exceeding 240. 
Could anyone with the experience help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a programming question and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you think you've found a bug your best solution is to open a bug report.

You are using a slightly out of date version of Ghostscript and a very out of date version of Acrobat. You haven't explained how you are using Acrobat to determine 'total coverage' or indeed what you mean by 'total coverage'.